# How do I use express.js with truffle contracts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, truffle

I was following a tutorial on Youtube on making a decentralized voting app on truffle: https://youtu.be/3681ZYbDSSk.

The source code is as follows: https://github.com/dappuniversity/election/tree/2019_update

The system has a backend with lite-server, the same as the official pet-shop tutorial and a simple frontend where users vote for their candidates.

This is fine until I wanted to add a login and sign up feature into the system. After some research, I found out that lite-server is not able to send Mysql queries like express.js or php, so I tried to implement this feature in express.js.

I created a new dir, `init truffle`, `npm install express`, then put everything from the original project to the new one. I created index.js, which I run as the server

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

// http://localhost:3000/
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  // Render login template
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I hope to include the compiled contracts using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));`, however somehow it can't recognize it, so I was forced to move the compiled contract into the public dir. Then I `nodemon index.js` again.
[The system failed to render the candidates detail, so it's blank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYPBj.png) [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rHxj.png) is how it should have look like.

In the app, the client-side app.js makes call to the web3.js api to get the details of candidates deployed on the blockchain. In my express app, it can only get the blockchain address but not the details. Here is the app.js (which can also be found on the github link above).

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: "0x0",
  hasVoted: false,

  init: function () {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function () {
    // TODO: refactor conditional
    if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        "http://localhost:7545"
      );
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    console.log("We are in initWeb3");
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function () {
    $.getJSON("Election.json", function (election) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(election);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      App.listenForEvents();

      return App.render();
    });
  },

  // Listen for events emitted from the contract
  listenForEvents: function () {
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      // Restart Chrome if you are unable to receive this event
      // This is a known issue with Metamask
      // https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2393
      instance
        .votedEvent(
          {},
          {
            fromBlock: 0,
            toBlock: "latest",
          }
        )
        .watch(function (error, event) {
          console.log("event triggered", event);
          // Reload when a new vote is recorded
          App.updateCounts();
        });
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    var electionInstance;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var content = $("#content");
    console.log("In render");

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function (err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });

    // Load contract data
    App.contracts.Election.deployed()
      .then(function (instance) {
        electionInstance = instance;
        console.log(electionInstance.candidatesCount());
        return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
      })
      .then(function (candidatesCount) {
        var candidatesResults = $("#candidatesResults");
        candidatesResults.empty();

        var candidatesSelect = $("#candidatesSelect");
        candidatesSelect.empty();

        for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
          electionInstance.candidates(i).then(function (candidate) {
            var id = candidate[0];
            var name = candidate[1];
            var voteCount = candidate[2];

            // Render candidate Result
            var candidateTemplate =
              "<tr><th>" +
              id +
              "</th><td>" +
              name +
              "</td><td id='vc_" +
              id +
              "'>" +
              voteCount +
              "</td></tr>";
            candidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);

            // Render candidate ballot option
            var candidateOption =
              "<option value='" + id + "' >" + name + "</ option>";
            candidatesSelect.append(candidateOption);
          });
        }
        return electionInstance.voters(App.account);
      })
      .then(function (hasVoted) {
        // Do not allow a user to vote
        if (hasVoted) {
          $("form").hide();
        }
        loader.hide();
        content.show();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  },

  updateCounts: function () {
    $("#content").hide();
    $("#loader").show();

    App.contracts.Election.deployed()
      .then(function (instance) {
        electionInstance = instance;
        return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
      })
      .then(function (candidatesCount) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
          electionInstance.candidates(i).then(function (candidate) {
            var id = candidate[0];
            var voteCount = candidate[2];
            var cell = document.getElementById("vc_" + id);
            if (cell != null) {
              cell.innerHTML = voteCount;
            }
          });
        }
        return electionInstance.voters(App.account);
      })
      .then(function (hasVoted) {
        // Do not allow a user to vote
        if (hasVoted) {
          $("form").hide();
        }
      });

    $("#content").show();
    $("#loader").hide();
  },

  castVote: function () {
    var candidateId = $("#candidatesSelect").val();
    App.contracts.Election.deployed()
      .then(function (instance) {
        return instance.vote(candidateId, { from: App.account });
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        // Wait for votes to update
        $("#content").hide();
        $("#loader").show();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
  },
};

$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    App.init();
    console.log("Init success");
  });
});
```

I noticed that web3.eth.getCoinbase works perfectly because the address is correctly shown, but somehow at the line `App.contracts.Election.deployed()`, it cannot get the details from the contract.

My question is, how do I fix my code so it can correctly show the details of the candidates? Because the sign up and login system can only work if the basic voting component is in place. Plus, how do I put it correctly so express.js can recognize my contracts in build/contracts?

Or are there other ways to make it work such as configuring lite-server to send mysql queries, or implementing this on xampp then use php to connect to mysql? Thank you very much.

P.S. I've tried to use express-box for this project. For whatever reasons, it cannot work. Whenever I tried to truffle compile, the vs code pops up and truffle did nothing, so I turned to creating a new express project instead.

Answer (score 0):

After a series of painstaking trial-and-error experiments. I've finally found the solution. On the line " $.getJSON("Election.json", function (election)", it sends out a http get request to the server asking for "Election.json". This compiled contract resides in build/contracts, so the server has to serve this json if the voting system has to work, otherwise, it would turn up a blank section for candidates.

The solution is simply add one more line in index.js that imports the json. Then, add one more endpoint that just serves that json when requested. The final code would look like this

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const path = require("path");
var json = require("./build/contracts/Election.json");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// http://localhost:3000/
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  // Render login template
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.get("/Election.json", function (request, response) {
  response.send(json);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now the system can find the json it needs to let user see the votes and vote as well.

If you have a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: I don't know, but, the stackoverflow community is colder than I thought. Like I am talking to myself